# How to get percentage of a column based on a given value

Tags: python, pandas

I have below dataset. I want to get the percentage of Survived which value is equal to 1.

```
     Survived                                               Name
0           0                            Braund, Mr. Owen Harris
1           1  Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...
2           1                             Heikkinen, Miss. Laina
3           1       Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)
4           0                           Allen, Mr. William Henry
5           0                                   Moran, Mr. James
6           0                            McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J
7           0                     Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard
8           1  Johnson, Mrs. Oscar W (Elisabeth Vilhelmina Berg)
9           1                Nasser, Mrs. Nicholas (Adele Achem)
```

I know I can get the value by this command:

`train_df.loc[train_df['Survived'] == 1].shape[0] / train_df.shape[0]`

but I am looking for a better solution. Is there a simpler way for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pd.Series.mean`

```
df.Survived.mean()

0.5
```

Comment: If I want to support more values, how can I do that? For example, `Survived` has three values, 0, 1 and 2. How can I calculate the value 1 among these three values?

Comment: You aren't being clear.  The average of `1` among all values that are `1` is `1`.  If you want the frequency of of `1` among all values, use `df.Survived.eq(1).mean()`.  If you want all at once use `df.Survived.value_counts(normalize=True)`